# iphone : Problem regarding facebook login page orientation in FBgraph Api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using FBGraph Api for facebook integration,

I have a TabBarController in app.

But when i get login facebook view it"s shows the Full View.

and can"t show the TabBarcontroller.

i want to resize the FaceBook Login Page,

How can i do that?

Comment: If it is shown as a modalviewcontroller, I'm afraid you can't.

Answer (score 1):

I answered in [FbGraph API in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395708/fbgraph-api-in-landscape-mode/11204567#11204567) so you only change the frame of webview and u r done

And if ur app only support portrait orientation then u dont need any thing just change the frame of webview